# Custom post-request with RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

My models work with the server via Ember's default `RESTAdapter`.

I just created a custom endpoint `/mail` on my server which sends an e-mail if provided a name, valid e-mail-adress and text.

How do I make Ember send that custom post-request? Is it possible without Ember.ajax at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me personally, I wouldn't use Ember-Data to handle that scenario; I generally only use Ember-Data to handle my persisted models. If you try to use Ember-Data for other AJAX calls, it's just going to become a mess. Remember that Ember-Data's job is to *manage your persisted data* and one way that it *can* do that is with AJAX calls. That doesn't mean that anything that requires an AJAX call should be handled with Ember-Data.

I have this same issue and I wrote a utility module that has functions for all of my non-model AJAX stuff. This makes it really easy to swap out for testing. Here's a small example:

```
// utils/ajax.js

export function sendHelpEmail(comment) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/contact_us',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ comment }),
            processData: false,
            statusCode: {
                200: () => Em.run(null, resolve),
                500: () => Em.run(null, reject)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then, I can do something like this in my controller:

```
import { sendHelpEmail} from '../utils/ajax.js';

export default Em.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        sendEmail() {
            sendHelpEmail(this.get('comment'));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Got any recommendations/links on `Ember.run`? Docs are quite reduced http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html

Comment: @hectorh30 For the API, check out the [source code](https://github.com/ebryn/backburner.js/blob/master/lib/backburner.js#L141). The args are `(target, method, args...)`. For understanding of the run loop, checkout out [this guide](https://github.com/ebryn/backburner.js/blob/master/lib/backburner.js#L141).

Comment: the second links point to the code as well. A guide would be very useful. Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit that comment yet, but here's the guide: https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/understanding-ember/run-loop/